# Issues casting shadow

Tags: three.js

I want my **tableBoard** (Surface of the table) and **tableLegs** to cast their shadows upon the **floor**

[image: Current Look]

**Light**

```
import * as THREE from "three";

export default ({ scene }) => {
    const lights = [];
    lights[0] = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 0);
    lights[0].position.set(0, 200, 0);
    lights[0].castShadow = true;
    scene.add(lights[0]);
  }
```

**Objects(Mesh)**

```
    tableLeg1.castShadow = true;
    tableBoard.castShadow = true;
    floor.receiveShadow = true;

    tableLeg1.add(floor);
    tableBoard.add(tableLeg1);
    scene.add(tableBoard);
```

**renderer**

```
  sceneSetup = () => {
    const width = this.el.clientWidth;
    const height = this.el.clientHeight;
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
    this.camera.position.z = 5;
    this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.el);
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
    this.el.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
  };
```

Comment: Try to configure your shadows similar to this code section (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/345e5042182fb64b9304c6fa474394aa29d3b3b7/examples/webgl_shadowmap_pointlight.html#L44-L46) in order to ensure your shadow casting and receiving objects lie in the shadow camera's frustum.

Comment: You're everywhere! Thanks Mugen, i'll check it out.